# AngularJS ng-click on mobile device fire at wrong position

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Ionic Framework to develop a mobile application for Android.

My issue is that I need to have a list of containers at random positions and are able to be clicked.

The list of containers are displayed correctly at the random positions but the click areas only work when i click at the top of the view, not at the position itself.

The clicking works fine in the mobile browsers at the correct position but when I run the app as a native application in Android, the clicks messed up.

It seems like **clicking areas are lined up at the top of the view**, does anyone know what is causing this?

The codes are here:

HTML file

```
<div class="col" ng-model="qtablelayout">
        <div qtable ng-model='qtable' ng-repeat='qtable in qtablelayout.qtables' class="tablediv" ng-class="qtable.tstatus" ng-style="{'left': {{qtable.x}}+'px', 'top':{{qtable.y}}+'px'}" ng-click="tblActions(qtable)">
            <h2>{{qtable.tableNo}}</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="tablesize">{{qtable.currentHP.qsize}}/{{qtable.maxSize}}</li>
                <li class="tabletime">{{qtable.tabletime.hours}}h {{qtable.tabletime.mins}}m {{qtable.tabletime.secs}}s</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS file

```
div.tablediv
{
    position: absolute;
    background: url("../img/table/tablestatus.png") no-repeat;
    color: #fff !important;
    width: 178px;
    height: 178px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The Controller side

```
$scope.tblActions = function(m)
    {
        alert("x:" + m.x + ",y:" + m.y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause of the problem is that I had an Ion-Refresher before the list of containers and it seemed to have shifted up the clicking areas together with the space for the Ion-Refresher.

It worked when I put the Ion-Refresher at the bottom of the HTML.